# From an urn containing $n$ balls numbered from $1$ to $n$, $3$ balls are extracted randomly

Tags: probability, statistics

From an urn containing $n$ balls numbered from $1$ to $n$, $3$ balls are extracted randomly (without reinsertion). Assuming there is concordance to the $k-th$ extraction if in this extraction the ball with number $k$ comes out, calculate the probability to have $3$ concordances,

**Solution**. Placing $A_k =$ {there is concordance to the $k-th$ extraction}, from the law of compound probability follows that the required probability in is given by

$P (A_1 ∩ A_2 ∩ A_3) = P (A_1) P (A_2 | A_1) P (A_3 | A_1 ∩ A_2) = 1/
n · 1/(n - 1) · 1/(n - 2)$

I don't understand why $P(A_1)=1/n$, is it because you have one possibility out of $n$ that the first ball is $1$?

I don't understand  why $P (A_2 | A_1)=1/(n-1)$ and $P (A_3 | A_1 ∩ A_2)=1/(n-2)$

Comment: "is it because you have one possibility out of n that the first ball is 1?": **yes**;


$P(A_2|A_1)=1/(n-1)$ because if you had concordance in the first extraction, then ball $2$ is still inside the urn and you have a probability of $1/(n-1)$ to get it. Similarly for the other conditional probability.

Comment: @Matteo That is an answer.  You should post it as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in comment I just re-post my comment, more properly, as an answer.

---

The answer to you question on the reason why 
$$P(A_1) = \frac{1}{n}$$
is on the **affirmative**.

Also, 
$$P(A_2|A_1)=\frac{1}{n−1}$$ 
because if you had concordance in the first extraction, then ball number $2$ is still inside the urn (among the other $n-1$ left after extraction) and you have a probability of $1/(n−1)$ to get it.

Similar reasoning  applies to the other conditional probability.